# click and deploy hadoop cluster on google cloud platform

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new to `Google Cloud`. I tried to click-and-deploy `Hadoop` cluster and I am always told that my quota are limited. But some days ago, I upgraded my free trial to a paid one ! (how can I check this in order to be sure that it was taken into account ?)

FYI, I tried to deploy instances using the `bdutil` tool, (`./bdutil --bucket mybucket -n 5 -P myproject --zone us-central1-a deploy`), and (for `-n 1` it works normally) : 5 instances are indeed created but no hadoop cluster is deployed and I get in my console

```
*-m' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10.
*-w-0' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10.
*-w-1' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10.
*-w-2' not yet sshable (1); sleeping 10....
```

Knowing that `ssh` keys are normally set in the project. 
How can I deal with that ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to check your available quotas, from your Developer console you can go to Compute Engine->VM Instances->Quotas page. This page will give you the quota information for Google Compute Engine.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366989/failing-to-deploy-hadoop-cluster-on-google-cloud) in order to troubleshoot your Hadoop ssh issue.